# Drupal 7 - Changing a content types heading style from <h3> to <h2>

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type on my Drupal installation called "Article". Which features a mandatory title (which I can't seem to make non mandatory) this title outputs as a `<h3>` tag.

How do I change it to `<h2>`?

You can see an example content type page at - https://www.workbooks.com/resources/marketing-roi

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Templates suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) and customize only the output of article content-types with `node--article.tpl.php`.

Based on Bartik node template, you can edit that part of the code:

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
  <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
</h2>
```

Comment: I saved a file called "node--article.tpl.php" at: \sites\all\themes\workbooks\css\ with the exact code you mentioned. But no difference seemed to have happened?

Comment: Don't save it in the css/ folder. And clear the cache. Also, the code I gave you is only a tiny part of the whole template code. You need to include the rest aswell.

Comment: Thanks, where should I save it then? And where I can find the rest of the template code?

Comment: If you are asking this kind of questions, you should probably start by reading the official documentation about how to customize a theme. What is "workbooks" theme? Did you create it yourself? Is it an existing theme that you download and install? It is important for me to know that.

Comment: It's a custom theme for our site, it was created by a 3rd party before I joined. Is it essential I learn PHP before reading how to customize a theme?

Comment: Yes, it is. Indeed. PHP is the base of everything in Drupal, even custom theme.

Comment: Thanks I may come back to this, need to learn Javascript first..!